# How can I search by first name and/or last name among WordPress users?

Tags: wordpress, search

By default, WordPress doesn't allow to search the users list by first and or last name. How do I enable this function in WordPress so that I can search anyone's name and see their account?

Answer (score 1):

Programmatic solution using the WP core `get_users` function.

```php
$search = 'name-looking-for';
$users = get_users( [
    'meta_query' => [
        'relation' => 'OR',
        [
            'key'     => 'first_name',
            'value'   => $search,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ],
        [
            'key'     => 'last_name',
            'value'   => $search,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ],
    ],
] );
```

For extra points if you want searches to start with the beginning of a name only.

For example if you search "ada" and want to get a user with first name of "adam" but not users with the first name of "vadam".

```php
/**
 * Strip the leading "%" from the LIKE condition so always start with the first
 * letter in a user's first or last name.
 */
add_filter( 'get_meta_sql', function( $sql ) use ( $search ) {
    global $wpdb;
    // Convert the "%" character into the queries' placeholder.
    $wildcard = \str_replace( "'", '', $wpdb->prepare( '%s', '%' ) );
    return \str_replace( "LIKE '{$wildcard}{$search[0]}", "LIKE '{$search[0]}", $sql );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this, shy of writing code or performing the search via a database query (which I wouldn't advise) is through a plugin.  There's a free plugin in the standard library, [User First Name / Full Name Search](https://wordpress.org/plugins/full-name-search-in-wp-admin/), that will do this for you.  It'll be installable via your admin panel's Add New feature under plugins, as it's in the WordPress directory.  Unlike what the name suggests, it does allow for searching by last names too.

Comment: Looks like you beat me to it, actually, haha.  I just saw your comment to his question!

Comment: Well, you were quicker on the draw. :)

Comment: I tried using that plugin yesterday and also today, however it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

This plugin allow users to search by : **Username, First name, Last name, Email or Business Name**.

Easiest way to **search** and **edit** users is to use this plugin.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/robust-user-search/
(I am the author, working on next version)

[image]

Comment: It's a good practice to mention when you created a thing that you're recommending.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getUsersBySurname($surname)
{
    global $wpdb;

    $users = $wpdb->get_results(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT * FROM wp_users as user 
                LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta as meta on meta.user_id = user.id 
                WHERE meta.meta_key = 'last_name' AND meta.meta_value = %s",
            $surname),
        ARRAY_A);

    return $users;
}
```

This function will return an array of users.
So you can use it like this. It will print every user email with the surname "Sanchez"

```
$users = getUsersBySurname("Sanchez");
if (!empty($users)) {
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        printf('<p>%s</p>', $user['user_email']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is two ways to do this.

1. You can use this [Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/full-name-search-in-wp-admin/)
2. You can use this [Code](https://really-simple-plugins.com/search-users-username-email-address-firstname-lastname/)

Comment: Where does that code need to go?

The plugin doesn't work. I had tried it yesterday and also today

Comment: @j92 I am pretty sure you take the code and put it into a plugin format. Then you can manually upload that new plugin to your WordPress manager. I am not 100% sure on this but I think that is how it works.