Use Query search full name: first name AND last name
I needed the WP search to be able to find first name AND last name, not OR.
'John Doe' should return John Doe.
I have found something here, it has a good idea, but it cannot find "John Doe", only all Johns and all Does.
So I have extended this solution. I answer my own question.
Here is my code...you can find "John Doe" now.
add_action( 'pre_user_query', function( $uqi ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $search = '';
    if ( isset( $uqi->query_vars['search'] ) )
        $search = trim( $uqi->query_vars['search'] );

    if ( $search ) {
        $search = trim($search, '*');

        if (stristr($search, " ")) { 
            
            $search_exp = explode(" ", $search);

            // 1. Query: Vorname
            $query1 = "SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta 
                      WHERE meta_key = 'first_name'
                      AND meta_value LIKE '%".$search_exp[0]."%'";
            $results1 = $wpdb->get_results($query1);
            $vorname_ids = array();
            foreach ($results1 as $key1 => $value1) {   
                $vorname_ids[] = $value1->user_id;
            }

            // 2. Query: Nachname
            $query2 = "SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta 
                      WHERE meta_key = 'last_name'
                      AND meta_value LIKE '%".$search_exp[1]."%'";
            $results2 = $wpdb->get_results($query2);
            $nachname_ids = array();
            foreach ($results2 as $key2 => $value2) {   
                $nachname_ids[] = $value2->user_id;
            }

            $fullname_ids = array_intersect($vorname_ids, $nachname_ids);
            $fullname_ids = implode(",", $fullname_ids);

            $search_meta = $wpdb->prepare("
            ID IN ('%s')", $fullname_ids);

            $uqi->query_where = str_replace(
                'WHERE 1=1 AND (',
                "WHERE 1=1 AND (" . $search_meta . " OR ",
                $uqi->query_where );
        } 
        else {
            $the_search = '%'.$search.'%';

            $search_meta = $wpdb->prepare("
            ID IN ( SELECT user_id FROM {$wpdb->usermeta}
            WHERE ( ( meta_key='first_name' OR meta_key='last_name' OR meta_key='billing_city' )
                AND {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_value LIKE '%s' )
            )", $the_search);

            $uqi->query_where = str_replace(
                'WHERE 1=1 AND (',
                "WHERE 1=1 AND (" . $search_meta . " OR ",
                $uqi->query_where );
        }   
    }
});


The original post is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40419053/wordpress-wp-user-query-search-first-name-last-name

DarkBee: Can we change the title to "User Query" instead of "Use Query"? Because the solution is especially for the WP User Query.
